# Relative Path being changed when executing from a Thread

Tags: java, eclipse, exec, relative-path

I'm making a web application that, at a certain point, starts a new thread and this thread executes a jar file from command line. 
The command line jar works fine when called from outside the application, but when i call it from the thread the relative path becomes C:\eclipse\ (i'm running the application from Eclipse) instead of the directory it's stored in, which messes up with its configuration since it looks for files in the wrong place.

The jar creates a log file, whenever i try to call it i have this line written in the log: "10/04/2012 17:09:03 - java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\eclipse\descriptors\analysis_engine\AggregateAE.xml"
The jar is not inside C:\eclipse. When i call it from prompt i have no problems, but when it's called from a new spawned thread i have this error. I've tried it on a production environment and i have the same problem (this time the base path is the server's one)

Considering that i can't modify all the paths, what could be a solution to this problem?

EDIT: this is the thread class that calls the jar

```
public class UimaThread extends Thread {
private int mode=0;
private String path;

public UimaThread(int mode, String path){
    this.mode=mode;
    this.path=path;
}

public void run() {
    Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Properties config = ConfigLoader.getConfig();

        String uimaPath=config.getProperty("uimaPath")+ControlPanelUtils.getDelimiter(config.getProperty("uimaPath"));
//uimaPath is the absolute path to the jar file, mode and path are just arguments passed to the jar
        run.exec("java -jar "+uimaPath+"uimachainfull.jar "+mode+" "+path); 

    }

}
```

The code running this is:

```
public void startUima() throws IOException, ServletException {
    Properties config = ConfigLoader.getConfig();
    UimaThread uimaThread = new UimaThread(2, config.getProperty("docPath"));
    uimaThread.start();
}
```

I need this to be executed asyncronously and outside the server, i've asked how to do that here in stackoverflow and i've been told to do so: [Calling an application from a web server asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973339/calling-an-application-from-a-web-server-asynchronously/9973480#9973480)

Comment: How are you "calling" this JAR? Show the code.

Also, I'm assuming that you're aware that Java web apps (JEE apps) are technically not allowed to spawn their own threads or access the file system. Some containers allow it, but I'm pretty sure doing so is against the JEE spec.

Comment: I've posted the code. I'm having no problems with threads spawning and file system. My application has to work a lot with file system accessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered how to do it, instead of using exec(String command) i had to use exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir) and the last argument (dir) is the working directory that can be passed as new argument